# Output parameter always returns 0

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Can anyone please take a look and see if they can find out why my output parameter is always returning 0.

Its proberbly something simple and I just cannot see it.

-----------------------SP----------------------------

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[test] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @SearchPhrase VarChar(100),
    @RecordsFound INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT  
          loads of stuff from table

    set @RecordsFound = @@ROWCOUNT;
END
```

------------------C# code-------------------------

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(dbConn))
                {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(spName, cn))
                    {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SearchPhrase", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100));
                    cmd.Parameters["@SearchPhrase"].Value = id;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RecordsFound", SqlDbType.Int));
                    cmd.Parameters["@RecordsFound"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                    List<News> Data = new List<News>();
                    try
                        {
                        cn.Open();
                        using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.Default))
                            {
                            if (rdr.HasRows)
                                {
                                while (rdr.Read())
                                    {
                                    Data.Add(new News
                                    {
                                        strNewsTitle            = (string)rdr["NewsTitle"],
                                        strNewsDatePosted       = (string)rdr["NewsDatePosted"],
                                        strNewsDescription      = (string)rdr["NewsDescription"],
                                        strLocationOfImageURL   = (string)rdr["ImageURL"],
                                        recordsReturned = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@RecordsFound"].Value) 
                                    });
                                    int recordsReturned1 = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@RecordsFound"].Value);
                                    }
                                int recordsReturned2 = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@RecordsFound"].Value);
                                }


                            return Data;
```

When testing stored procedure i can see that @RecordsFound does return a value, so I think problem is with my code.

Thanks

George

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[On MSDN at this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

> If your Command contains output parameters or return values, they will
>   not be available until the DataReader is closed.

```
using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.Default))
{
    if (rdr.HasRows)
    {
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            Data.Add(new News
            {
                strNewsTitle = (string)rdr["NewsTitle"],
                strNewsDatePosted = (string)rdr["NewsDatePosted"],
                strNewsDescription = (string)rdr["NewsDescription"],
                strLocationOfImageURL = (string)rdr["ImageURL"],
                recordsReturned = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@RecordsFound"].Value) 
            });
            // NOT AVAILABLE HERE - READER IS OPEN
            // int recordsReturned1 = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@RecordsFound"].Value);
        }
        // STILL OPEN
        //int recordsReturned2 = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@RecordsFound"].Value);
    }
}
// Data reader closed and disposed, get output parameter here or never
int recordsReturned2 = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@RecordsFound"].Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
```

No row count enabled, hence 0 as default.

Comment: Or you are right or [this docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189837.aspx) on MSDN are wrong `The @@ROWCOUNT function is updated even when SET NOCOUNT is ON.`

Comment: Hi flem, removed that still returns 0, I have put @RecordsFound in 3 places all return 0